# Open different activities when user selects ActionBar search option

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have a action bar with search view, when user selects search button on the keyboard after entering the search text in search view. I want to start a new activity depending on few parameters.

In my current implementation when user selects search button, then it always opens same activity which is defined in manifest file, how can I change this behavior.

For reference my action search implementation is similar to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) tutorial.

Comment: Can you provide some code please?

Comment: Yeah and do you mean that the EXTRA parameters that you pass to the Activity are ignored and default ones appear all the time??

Comment: The code is exactly similar to the tutorial, and I don't want to pass any Extra data to the activity, I just want to open two different activities when user selects the search button, depending on some parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for a `SearchActivity` and you've completed the tutorial mentioned then you should proceed to the next tutorial that explains  [how to store and search your data](http://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html). The first tutorial was just how to have a `SearchActivity` the next one is how about how to use it to query your data set